# Are there uncountably many surjections from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Statement: There are uncountably many surjections from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

Is the following proof valid:

The real numbers are uncountable.

There exists a bijection between the set of real numbers and the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Given a function, $f$, from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$, construct a surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, denoted $g$, as follows:

We map the $n$th composite number to $n$, and the nth prime, to $f(n)$.

Clearly this is a surjection since the composite numbers are countable. Clearly different functions $f$ lead to different surjections $g$. Since there are uncountably many $f$s, there are uncountably many surjections $g$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this would work.

Somewhat simpler would be to divide into even and odd numbers instead of composites and primes (by the way, you haven't specified what happens to $0$ and $1$), but the idea is perfectly good.

You can even get uncountably many *bijections* by letting $g$ swap $2n$ and $2n+1$ whenever $f(n)=1$ and leave them unchanged when $f(n)=0$.